# equation and dot symbol in brackets

Tags: matlab, equation, brackets

I want to calculate the result of the expression which is stored in variable a:

```
a = ([b.c]<10);
```

What will do this expression? Is it something like dividing?

Answer (score 2):

I would guess `b` is a [struct](http://www.mathworks.se/help/matlab/ref/struct.html) with a field named `c`. This means `b.c` is a variable just as any other. 
Type `whos b` to see if this assumption is correct.

If this is correct, the brackets `[]` are unnecessary, as `[x] == x`. *EDIT: As Luis points out, this is not true if `b` is an array of structs. Check out his answer!*

```
a = x < 10
```

is a logical statement, where you will get a `1` for every `x(k) < 10` and `0` for every `x(k) >= 10`.

```
b.c = [1 5 10 4 12];
a = ([b.c]<10)

b.c =
   1    5   10    4   12
a =
   1    1    0    1    0
```

Comment: The brackets do have some use if `b` is an array of structs; see my answer

Answer (score 1):

In the most general case, `b` may be an **array of structs**. For example, let us define

```
>> b(1).c = 5;
>> b(2).c = 7;
>> b(3).c = 11;
```

In that case, `b.c` gives you a [comma-separated list](http://www.mathworks.es/es/help/matlab/matlab_prog/comma-separated-lists.html?s_tid=doc_12b) of the values in the `c` field of all structs in the array:

```
>> b.c
ans =
     5
ans =
     7
ans =
     11
```

`[b.c]` just [concatenates](http://www.mathworks.es/es/help/matlab/matlab_prog/comma-separated-lists.html?s_tid=doc_12b#br2js35-12) that comma-separated list into a vector:

```
>> [b.c]
ans =
     5     7     11
```

Finally, `a = ([b.c]<10);` stores in `a` the result of the [comparison](http://www.mathworks.es/es/help/matlab/ref/relationaloperators.html) of those values against `10`:

```
>> a=([b.c]<10)
a =
     1     1     0
```

By the way, the (rounded) parentheses are not needed:

```
>> a=[b.c]<10
a =
     1     1     0
```

Answer (score 0):

See the [description](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/specialcharacters.html) of `[]`:

> Brackets are used to form vectors and matrices. [6.9 9.64 sqrt(-1)] is
>   a vector with three elements separated by blanks. [6.9, 9.64, i] is
>   the same thing. [1+j 2-j 3] and [1 +j 2 -j 3] are not the same. The
>   first has three elements, the second has five.

Now see the [description](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/symbol-reference.html#bsgigzp-23) of `.`.

This means that you'll get a vector of 1's and 0's where 1 will appear in each place that is greater than 10, and 0 otherwise.